# convert list<Object> to array of <Id> in java 8 stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

So I have User class

```
User{
    id
    name
}
```

& I need to convert `List<User>` to Array of  using stream so one way I am doing is to convert into list and then to array

```
coll.stream().map(am -> am.getId())
             .collect(Collectors.<Integer>toList())
             .toArray(new Integer[0])
```

but I think there should be another approach to directly convert into array rather than adding in list and then convert into array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` from Stream:

```
Integer[] ids = coll.stream()
    .map(am -> am.getId())
    .toArray(Integer[]::new)
```

which will create array from the stream rather than a list.

Comment: `User::getId` makes it even more descriptive than `am -> am.getId()` (IMHO)

Comment: Is `id` (and `getId()`) an `int` or an `Integer`? It makes a difference to what type of array you should be using.

Answer (score 6):

Unless there is a really good reason to collect into a `Integer[]` you're probably looking for:

```
int[] ids = coll.stream()
                .mapToInt(User::getId)
                .toArray();
```